# Python - Splitting data from text file using a delimiter

Tags: python, pandas, delimiter

I am trying to read a set of text files and have them saved to a Dataframe. Thanks to @jezrael I have managed to get this working as shown below:

```
list_ = []
dfs = []
for file_ in allFiles:
    with open(file_) as fp:
        lines1 = fp.read().split('\n')
        b = [i.split('~', 1)[1].split('*') for i in lines1]
        df = pd.DataFrame(b)
        dfs.append(df)

dfbig = pd.concat(dfs, ignore_index=True)
dfbig.to_csv('file.csv')
```

I however see there are a few rows that have multiple entries of `('~')` and hence each time when `('~')` occurs more than once in a row it just performs the split once. I am trying to see how could I modify the above code such that the split happens each time `('~')` appears.

Sample data:

```
[ABC*DEF*123>~123*999*HHH~HELLO*TEST*DATA]
```

Expected output:

```
123 999 HHH
HELLO TEST DATA
```

Comment: @jezrael, continuing from our previous question. Thanks..

Comment: Can you add some sample data?

Comment: the best with some problematic lines.

Comment: I think that a regular expression would work better here

Comment: @jezrael, I have pasted one such line where I am currently facing this problem. hope this helps

Comment: How is necessary parse data? Because with solution above should working nice

Comment: Can u provide sample output?

Comment: check it by `lines1 = ['ABC*DEF*123>~123*999*HHH~HELLO']
b = [i.split('~', 1)[1].split('*') for i in lines1]`

Comment: @jezrael, the solution works just fine. However in cases where there are multiple ('~') its actually needs to be a new line but since its part of the same list it just gets added as a new column in the Dataframe. Ideally that should be a new line and hence trying to see if we can get that setup accordingly. Thanks.

Comment: @scottmartin - Just tested solution and added simplified final solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change:

```
b = [i.split('~', 1)[1].split('*') for i in lines1]
```

to list comprehension with flattening and spliting by all `~` values with filtering out first value:

```
b = [x.split('*') for i in lines1 for x in i.split('~')[1:]]
```

Verifying:

```
lines1 = ['ABC*DEF*123>~123*999*HHH~HELLO*TEST*DATA']
b = [x.split('*') for i in lines1 for x in i.split('~')[1:]]
print (b)
[['123', '999', 'HHH'], ['HELLO', 'TEST', 'DATA']]
```

Then solution should be change with `extend`:

```
list_ = []

allFiles = glob.glob('csv/*.*')
for file_ in allFiles:
    with open(file_) as fp:
        lines1 = fp.read().split('\n')
        b = [x.split('*') for i in lines1 for x in i.split('~')[1:]]
        list_.extend(b)

dfbig = pd.DataFrame(list_)
```